# nvme External USB Drive Error ''Request failed due to a fatal device hardware error''

Tags: nvme

I have an NVME M.2 (Samsung PM871a) and I ca not get access to any data. Its connected to windows 10 pro via USB
externally.
In Disk Management. It shows ‘’Disk 1 Unknown Not Initialized’’ When I right click on it ‘’Initialise Disk’’ is Greyed Out and when I select ‘’Off Line’’ I get the error ‘’Request failed
due to a fatal device hardware error’’

Any ideas guys…?

Comment: "Any ideas guys…?" - My first thought is the USB enclosure does not actually supported NVMe drives.

Comment: Did it used to work & just failed, or never worked?

Comment: It might be corrupted, Its a possibility. So you should put claim for warranty if its available. And before that, try to connect it to some other PC with external USB, just to be on safe side. If its corrupted.

Comment: 100% guys the board in the drive has failed. Replaced with new board all is well.....